# How to implement Line Feed in PowerBuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

I have writen a script below that performs a line feed behavior (see attached image as reference output). But when I transmitted the text file via FTP, it results to a feedback error of  "Delimiters of the file is incorrect. It is still carriage return & line feed. It should just be a line feed. "

Hoping for a response from anybody....

PBScript:

```
Long ll_row
ll_row = dw_Outbound.InsertRow(0)
dw_Outbound.SetITem(ll_row,'message',as_message)
as_message = ""
```

[image: text buffer]

File Write Function Script :

```
    //Retrieve Transaction Set Header
    ids_TSH = CREATE DataStore
    ids_TSH.DataObject = 'd_inventory_advice_transetheader'
    ids_TSH.SetTransObject( SQLCA )
    ids_TSH.Retrieve()
    IF ids_TSH.ROwCount() = 1 THEN 
        ls_Msg += Trim(ids_TSH.Object.headerid[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(ids_TSH.Object.setidcode[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(ids_TSH.Object.setctrlnum[1])
        ls_Msg += "|" 
        //Set LineFeed
        //ls_Msg += "~n"
        of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
        of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)
    END IF

    //Retrieve Beginning Segment
    ids_BIA = CREATE DataStore
    ids_BIA.DataObject = 'd_inventory_advice_begsegment'
    ids_BIA.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
    ids_BIA.Retrieve()
    IF ids_BIA.RowCount() = 1 THEN
        ls_Msg += Trim(ids_BIA.Object.biaid[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(ids_BIA.Object.trnsetpcode[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(ids_BIA.Object.reptypecode[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(ids_BIA.Object.refid[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + is_BIADATE
        ls_Msg += "|"   
        of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
        of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)
    END IF

    //Assigned DateTime Reference
    ls_Msg += "DTM"
    ls_Msg += "*" + "007"        
    ls_Msg += "*" + is_BIADATE
    ls_Msg += "*" + is_Time
    ls_Msg += "*" + "UT"
    ls_Msg += "|" 
    of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
    of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)

    //Assigned Reference Identification
    ls_Msg += "REF"
    ls_Msg += "*" + "EO"         
    ls_Msg += "*" + "SAPMBT01" //ISA06 SENDERID : SPI818TEST
    ls_Msg += "|"
    of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
    of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)

    lds_Data = CREATE DataStore
    lds_Data.DataObject = 'd_inventory_advice_subinv_phldef'
    lds_Data.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
    lds_Data.Retrieve()

    lds_Name = CREATE DAtaStore
    lds_Name.DataObject = 'd_inventory_advice_nameheader'
    lds_Name.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
    lds_Name.Retrieve()

    IF lds_Name.RowCount() = 1 THEN 
        ls_Msg += Trim(lds_Name.Object.nameid[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Name.Object.entityidcode[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Name.Object.entityname[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Name.Object.idcodequal[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Data.Object.subinv[1])
        ls_Msg += "|"
        of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
        of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)

        ls_Msg += Trim(lds_Name.Object.addressid[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Name.Object.addressinfo[1])
        ls_Msg += "|"
        of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
        of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)

        ls_Msg += Trim(lds_Name.Object.glid[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Name.Object.cityname[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + 'ML' //STATE OR PROVINCE CODE
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Name.Object.postalcode[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Name.Object.countrycode[1])
        ls_Msg += "|"
        of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
        of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)
    END IF

    //Administration Communication Contact
    /*lds_Contact = CREATE DataStore
    lds_Contact.DataObject = 'd_inventory_advice_contact'
    lds_Contact.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
    lds_Contact.Retrieve()
    IF lds_Contact.RowCOunt() = 1 THEN 
        ls_Msg += Trim(lds_Contact.Object.accid[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Contact.Object.fnccode[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Contact.Object.name[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Contact.Object.numqual[1])
        ls_Msg += "*" + Trim(lds_Contact.Object.telnum[1])
        ls_Msg += "|"
        of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
        of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)
    END IF*/

    //Initialize DataStore To Handle Line Item RowCount 
    ids_ITem = CREATE DAtaStore 
    ids_ITem.DataObject = 'd_edi_outbound_message_external'
    ids_ITem.SetTransObject( SQLCA )

    IF lds_Data.RowCOunt() > 0 THEN 
        FOR ll_Data = 1 To lds_Data.RowCOunt()      
            ls_item = lds_Data.getitemString(ll_Data, 'itemcode')
            ls_qtyonhand = String(lds_Data.getItemNumber(ll_Data,'sohqty'))
            ls_qtyavailable = String(lds_Data.getItemNumber(ll_Data,'availableqty'))
            ls_subinv = lds_Data.getItemString(ll_Data,'subinv')        

            ls_Msg = "LIN**MG*" + ls_item + "|"
            of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
            of_getItemCodeRowCount(ls_Msg)
            of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)

            ls_Msg = "QTY*17*" + ls_qtyonhand + "|"
            of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
            of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)

            ls_Msg = "QTY*33*" + ls_qtyavailable + "|"
            of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
            of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)

            ls_Msg = "UIT*EA|"
            of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
            of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)
        NEXT
    END IF

    ll_Filter = ids_ITem.RowCount()
    //Transaction Total
    ls_Msg += "CTT*" + String(ll_Filter) + "|"
    of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)
    of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)

    //Retrieve Set Trailer
    ids_TST = CREATE DataStore
    ids_TST.DataObject = 'd_inventory_advice_transettrailer'
    ids_TST.SetTRansObject(SQLCA)
    ids_TST.Retrieve()

    IF ids_TST.RowCount() = 1 THEN  
        of_getInventoryAdviceTranRowCount(ls_Msg)
        //Get the  DataStore RowCount For Trasaction Set Trailer
        is_SetTrailer = String(ids_InvTranTrailer.RowCount())

        ls_Msg += Trim(ids_TST.Object.trailerid[1])+ "*" + is_SetTrailer + "*"
        ls_Msg += Trim(ids_TSH.Object.setctrlnum[1]) + "|"
    END IF
    of_ReturnOutboundMessage(ls_Msg)

    //Note: Function below should not be remove.
    //of_getInventoryAdviceGroupTrailer()
    //of_getInventoryAdviceControlTrailer()

    GETDATETIME:
    ls_ServerDate = gnv_app.of_getServerDateTime()

    IF is_ServerDateNull = ls_ServerDate THEN GOTO GETDATETIME
    is_ServerDateNull = ls_ServerDate   

    FilePath = String(dw_path.Object.outboundfilepath[1])
    FileName = 'EDI_846_' + ls_ServerDate + '.TXT'
    FileDir = FilePath + '/' + FileName

    dw_Outbound.SaveAs(FileDir, TEXT!, FALSE)

    dw_Outbound.Reset()
```

Comment: You are showing the code that inserts the text into a datawindow, could you show the code that is getting the dw text and how you are sending via ftp? Is it a command line tool, a third-party component?

Comment: @ Seki. Basically that script is inside a local function, of_ReturnOutboundMessage() with an argument type of string : as_message. I just noticed when i ran in debugged mode, once it was inside that function it never step out again and it falls to activate event in pfc_w_master. Is there an error if it behaves that way though i successfully generated the text file during the runtime mode.

Comment: Yes FTP is a third-party component. Below is the script i have made inside the FTP tool.

Local-CD "E:\SCHNDRUAT\SCHNDR_OUTBOUND"

Remote-CD "from_schndrtest"

ShowTransferDialogs

Binary

Send "E:\SCHNDRUAT\SCHNDR_OUTBOUND\*.*" "/from_schndrtest"

NoTransferDialogs

Comment: How `of_ReturnOutboundMessage()` is making the final message is relevant, as you must take care of the usage of `~r` and / or `~n` the  two possible line delimiters. Also it can also depend on how you are sending: directly to you 3rd-party tool as a string, or by writing a file first and asking the tool to send it...

Comment: There is a scheduled task configured for the batch file. inside the batch file, 1st command line is to execute the PB application. then second command line is to call the FTP script then transmits the text file. Actually i did not use ~r or ~n. I've used dw_controlname.InsertRow(0) instead.

Comment: I understand that you use `InsertRow()` to store some text in your `dw_controlname` but *how* do you get back the whole content for sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you've run into is the difference between the concept of [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) between different operating systems. PowerBuilder is (at point of this writing, you haven't described which function is transporting data from the DataWindow into a text file) creating a file with Windows-style newlines (CR+LF, or in PowerScript, `"~r~n"`), whereas your FTP or FTP recipient (not clear where this message is coming from) wants Unix-style newlines (LF, or in PowerScript, `"~n"`). If you want control over how the newlines are generated, you're going to have to write the file yourself (in script, using `FileOpen()`, `FileWrite()`, etc... and not relying on PB to generate newlines, so no `FileOpen (..., LineMode!, ...)`)

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: i have provided the script of FileWrite() function. As you see after each segment of line, it calls the function of_ReturnOutboundMessage() to store the data of each segments. And this script working fine and generates the file with no error. What i'm thinking of is to revised my script and make use of "~n" since the requirement is line feed only. Any comment ?

Comment: There's a lot of missing detail, but from what's been revealed, the dw.SaveAs() is what's introducing the CRLFs. As above, I'd expect you'd need to remove the dependence on the DataWindow's SaveAs().

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the inputs and thank you for helping out. By the way i just want to share how i was able to resolved the issue.

Inside the IF lds_Data.RowCOunt() > 0 ELSE THEN construct, i have made a wrong concatenation which is  ' ls_Msg = ' which is supposed to be ' ls_Msg += '. Script has been revised and the files were successfully processed.